# Counterpart of regular expressions for parsing nested strucures

Tags: regex, parsing, formal-languages

Regular expressions are a standard tool used for parsing strings across many languages. However their scope of applicability is limited. Regular expressions can only match a list. There is no way to describe arbitrary deep nested structures using regular expressions. Question: what is a technology/framework as widely used/spread and as standatd as regular expessions are that can match tree structures (produce AST).

Comment: "Regular expressions can only match a list." Huh? The RE `(a|b)+` is arguably not a list... Also, you might want to look up terms like "context-free grammar" or "context-free language" - although that's barely scratching the surface of different kinds of languages that are not "regular expressions" or "regular languages", it should at least give you some starting points in the wonderful world of languages and parsing...

Comment: Fwiw - some regex engines can do recursion and maintain an internal stack.

Comment: @twalberg `abbabbaababbaababaaba` looks rather like a tree than a list doesnt it?

Comment: @AlekseyBykov Not really. It could be *interpreted* as a tree, I suppose, but it looks like a "string of length at least one consisting of only 'a' and 'b' in any order", which is exactly what that regular expression describes. Regular expressions are generally not responsible for assigning any semantic meaning to a string - only recognizing that a string does or does not match a certain structure.

Answer (score 3):

Regular expressions describe a finite-state automaton.

Since the late 1960's, the "bread and butter" of parsing (though not necessarily the "state of the art") has been push-down automata generated by parser generators according to "LR" algorithms like LALR(1).

The connection to regular expressions is this: the parsing machine does in fact use rules very similar to regular expressions in order to recognize viable prefixes.  The "shift" state transitions among the "core LR(0) items" constitute a finite automaton, and can be described by a regular expression. The recursion is is handled thanks to the semantic action of pushing symbols onto a stack when doing the "shifts", and removing them ("reducing").  Reductions rewrite a portion of the stack, and perform a "goto" to another state. This type of goto, together with the stack, is absent in the regular expression automaton.

Parse Expression Grammars are also related to regular expressions. Regular expressions themselves can be endowed with recursion. Firstly, we can take pieces of regular expressions and give them names, and then construct bigger regular expressions by writing expressions which invoke these names. (Such as feature is found in the `lex` tool where you can define a named expressions like `letters [A-Za-z]+` and refer to it later as `{letters}`.   Now suppose you allow circular references, like `letters [A-Za-z]{letters}?`. You now have recursion; the only problem is to adjust the model in order to implement it.

Implementations of so-called "regular expressions" in various modern languages and environments in fact support recursion. Perl-compatible regular expressions (PCRE) support it, for instance.

Expressions that feature recursion or backreferencing are not handled by the classic NFA compilation route (possibly converted to a DFA); they cannot be.

How the above `letters` recursion can be handled is with actual recursion. The `?` operator can be implemented as a function which tries to match its respective argument object. If it succeeds, then it consumes whatever it has matched, otherwise it consumes nothing. That is to say, the regular expression can be converted to a syntax tree, and interpreted "as is" rather than compiled to a state machine (or trivially compiled to functions corresponding to the nodes of the tree), and such interpretation can naturally handle recursion. The interpretation then constitutes, effectively, a syntax-directed recursive-descent parser. (Note how I avoided left recursion in defining `letters` to make that example compatible with this approach).

Example: parenthesis-matching regex:

```
par-match := ({par-match})|
```

This gets compiled to a tree:

```
              branch-op    <-- "par-match" name points at this node
               /   \  
    catenate-op     <empty>
     /      \ 
   "("       catenate-op
             /          \        
          {par-match}    ")"
```

This can then converted to a recursive descent parser, or interpreted directly.

Pattern matching starts by invoking the top-level "branch-op". This operator simply tries all of the alternatives. Suppose the input is empty. Then the left alternative will fail: it demands an open parenthesis. So then the right alternative will succeed: empty matches empty. (The operators either "fail" or indicate "success" and consume input.)

But suppose your input is `(())`. The left `catenate-op` will in turn invoke its left subtree, which matches and consumes the left parenthesis, leaving `())`. It will then invoke its right subtree, another `catenate-op`. This `catenate-op` matches its left subtree, which triggers recursion into the top level via the named `par-match` references.  That recursion will match and consume `()`, leaving `)`. The `catenate-op` then invokes its right subtree which matches `)`. Control returns up to `branch-op`.  (Though the left side of `branch-op` matched something, `branch-op` must still try the other alternative; more than one branch can match, and some can match longer than others.)

This is closely related to [Parsing Expression Grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar) work.

Practically speaking, the recursive definition could be encoded into the regex syntax somehow. Say we invent some new operator like `(?name:definition)` which means "match `definition` which is allowed to contain invocations of itself via `name`. The invocation syntax could be `(*name)`, so that we can write the `par-match` example as `(?par-match:\((*par-match)\)|)`. The combinations `(?` and `(*` are invalid under "classic" regex syntax and so we can use them for extension.

As a final note, regexes correspond to grammars. That is the fundamental connection btween regexes and parsing. That is to say, regexes correspond to a particular subset of grammars describe only regular languages. An example of a grammar which describes a regular language:

```
S -> A | B
B -> b
A -> A a | c
```

Although there is `A -> A ...` recursion, this is still regular, and corresponds to the regex `ac*|b`, which is just a more compact way to denote the same language.  The grammar lets us notate languages that aren't regular and for which we can't write a regex, but as we have seen, we can extend the regex notation and semantics to express some of these things. Regular expressions aren't separate from grammars. The two aren't counterparts, but rather one is a special case or subset of the other.

Answer (score 0):

Parser generators like Yacc, Bison, and derivatives are what you're after. They aren't as widespread as regular expressions because they generate actual C code. There are translations like Jison for example which implement the Yacc/Bison syntax using javascript. I know there are similar tools for other languages.

I get the impression Parsing expression grammar systems are up and coming though.